# primefaces input text passing to managedbean as null in dialog(modal=true)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use primefaces 5.1 and jsf 2.2 .I have a dialog (modal=true) .I have fullpageLayout.And have menuItems.İf u clicked menuA,opening datatable.And Firstly u select row and then showing up dialog.Enter th password and submit it.All works fine.and in the same page(if u didn't click to menu items etc.) u can do that properly.But if u click menuA from MenuItems in fullpagelayout AGAIN.it does not work.Password value is passing as
null to managedBean.So showing password required message.*(managed bean scoped is viewScoped)*

**codes:**

```
<h:form id="bla">
    //datatable
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="..dialog.."
                                onstart="PF('dialog').show()" />
</h:form>

<p:dialog header="Welcome" widgetVar="dialog" position="center center"
    closeOnEscape="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
    appendTo="@(body)" draggable="false" resizable="false" modal="true">

    <h:form id="blabla">
        <p:password id="password" value="#{bean.value}"
            requiredMessage="required password!" required="true">
            <f:validateLength minimum="4" maximum="6" />
        </p:password>

        <p:commandButton value="Go" update="growl" action="#{bean.valueOp()}"
            oncomplete="PF('dialog').hide()">
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Why the password value passing to backing bean as a null?Thanks in advance..
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me. Your server log shows no exceptions? What about the browser Developer Tools (Chrome or Firefox) -- what does the POST reply say?

Comment: yes,log shows no exception.I added a log.info(bla); to getter/setter.They don't appear in the console log,When I tried again.I am adding a photo.

Comment: "*When I enter the password and submit **again**, it's not working*". How does this happen **again**? The dialog is hidden after the given `<p:commandButton>` is pressed - `oncomplete="PF('dialog').hide()"`. Does it mean that it does not work, when you select the same or another row after the first attempt in the said `<p:dataTable>` to open the dialog again? What happens, when you remove `appendTo="@(body)"` from the given `<p:dialog>` in its entirely?

Comment: yes When I select the same/other row,It doesnot work.Dialog window stays behind the dark so looks back but unavailable.

Comment: Tiny, I apologize for my misinformation.I have fullpageLayout.And have menuItems.İf u clicked menuA,opening datatable.And Firstly u select row and then showing up dialog.İnput to password and submit it.All works fine.and in the same page(if u didn't click to menu items etc.) u can do that again properly.But if u click menuA from MenuItems in fullpagelayout AGAIN.it does not work.I apologize again.